# Transferring file from One servlet to another servlet which is residing in a seperate server

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, servlets, file-upload

I have two Java applications A and B.A will upload two files(using multipart) two the tomcat server. And in the servlet of A I want to redirect to a servlet in Application B which is hosted in another system(using response.sendRedirect()). But How can I copy/transfer the uploaded files to the servlet in B?? Database sharing is not preferred.

Can I do this using any of the following methodes.
1.URL Connection
2.Session
3.Adding to response object

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you  could use Apache's HTTPClient to POST a file to servlet, [See example](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload), In this method your first servlet will first receive the file and then it will act as HTTP client for the second servlet and it will make a POST to second servlet

Also you could transfer file to another server using SFTP if your server is able to communicate on SFTP

Comment: i will try this and let you know.. The main problem is since I am using response.SendRedirect it will create a new request object. Then all the data related to previous request will loose.

Comment: Yes redirecting will create new request, you should rather create a HTTP call from servlet itself and give the response to user right away

Comment: Create a new thread that will make the another HTTP POST call asynchronously from your doPost() method of first servlet, and for how to make call see http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365153/HttpClient-and-FileUpload

Comment: Thanks Jigar. Once the issue is resolved I will put the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - probably the easiest way is for A. to do an HTTP "POST" to B (option 3).

You can also try the File Uploads package in Apache Commons:

- http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

You *cannot* do it from a session.

And the problem with a raw socket is that B will need a server, a "listener", to accept a connection.  If you use an HTTP post, you've *already* got a ready-made listener: your web server :)  Otherwise, you'd need to use something like FTP ... or write your own service.

Comment: I have tried the following code                                           ServletOutputStreamop = response.getOutputStream();  
         System.out.println("hi"); 
         System.out.println(dataBytes.length);
         response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        op.write(dataBytes);
      
       op.close();
         op.flush();
           
      response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8181/teste/Rec"); But I got illegal State exception..